# Tweeter rate limit

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to get information on an account's followers.
Despite I use both the wait_on_rate_limit and a time.sleep approach, I still get the rate limit error.
Can you help me to understand why?

thank you

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, timeout=10)
c=tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="Twitter").items()
while True: 
   try:
       user = c.next()
       print user.screen_name
   except tweepy.TweepError:           
       time.sleep(60 * 15)
       continue        
   except StopIteration:
       break
```

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: Debug if your code really waits (is the exception an ``TweepError`` or is there some ``RateLimit`` exception?) and output the rates twitter reports (tweepy has a function to for this). You may also try to avoid hitting the limit, as twitter recommends not to hit it too often. Maybe they increase the wait time for you, when you hit it a few times, so really check the output of the current rate limits.